# Firebase realtime database is not loading

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am trying to connect firebase to my python app. I need realtime database because I will build another mobile app using flutter and connect it to that database. I need this data in realtime. The problem is that during creating this database, when I get to the rules section, it keeps loading and never create it, when I refresh the site, it shows that it has been created, but it just keeps loading. Is there something wrong or this is from my side?

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly: is this happening in the Firebase console? If so, can you check if there are any messages in the JavaScript developer console of your browser? I'd also recommend trying again in an incognito browser with all extensions enabled, on another browser, and on another network.

Comment: finally, thank you @FrankvanPuffelen , indeed switching the network was the key.

Comment: Good to hear Omar.  --- You might want to check if the network you were on is silently blocking web sockets in that case. The Firebase SDKs normally fall back to long-polling on networks that don't support web sockets, but it seems like that didn't happen here in the console.